# Navigation bar Height, what is the best solution to set height?

Tags: objective-c

When you use View that related to Navigation Controller, it will have Navigation Bar more high, but what to do if my view is based on Tab Bar Controller ? The Title Text possition is almost jam the timer on status bar. Is it possible to adjust margin or padding, or even adjust the Navigation Bar height ?

---

### [LINK TO IMAGAE](http://www.royalmassasje.com/test2.html)

Comment: you can't modify it as it's what apple defines. You can however set the status bar hidden, and then you gain 20 more points

Answer (score 0):

I set the Storyboard like this:

Tab Bar Controller--->Navigation Controller--->myView
Yezzz, it works. But I am not sure if this is the wrong way ? If not this is very good news for me.